# Do we have an option to select the SSRS single Parameter from multiple Drop down values and enter multiple custom values at the same time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, crystal-reports

Do I have an option in the SSRS to select a multiple value parameter by selecting values from a drop down list and also enter custom values for the same parameter at the same time?

In Crystal Report I have option something like that, wondering to see if have that flexibility in SSRS as well?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: The only way would be to have a separate parameter to the dropdown that allows users to enter a value that is not available on the dropdown. Then adjust your where clause to accomodate the same

Comment: "Why build one, when you can have two at twice the price?" Why not use 2 parameters? `WHERE (FIELD IN (@PARAMETER1) OR FIELD IN (@PARAMETER2) )`